# How can i know the width and height of html elements?

Tags: javascript, html

i want to know the width and height of the html elements like divs body and tables.
is this possible ? i want the calculated width,height and not the one that i apply to the elements.
using jquery would be fine.
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this easily (and without jQuery) with **element.offsetWidth** and **element.offsetHeight**

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [dimensions](http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/) functions will be able to help. For example, the height() function

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://api.jquery.com/height/